# Not able to read sms inbox

Tags: java, android, sms, xml-parsing, android-service

Hi i am reading inbox using service but i m getting null pointer exception when i am creating cursor to read inbox previously i was able to read the sms with the same code now i want to store these sms into xml file in sd card but i am getting a null pointer exception . any help will be appreciated. 
my code is here

// **enter code here**

```
public class CreateBackupXml extends Service 
{
CreateBackup createBackup = null;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstance)
{

    Log.d("service","inside on create of service");
}
public void onDestroy()
{

}
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Creating Back up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("animation", "animation should be Start");
    createBackup = new CreateBackup();
    createBackup.createXml("all");
}

public class CreateBackup
{
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("");
    Cursor cur=null;
    public void createXml(String choice)
    {
        if(choice=="all")
        {
            this.readSms("Inbox");
        }
    }
    public void readSms(String folder)
    {

        if(folder.equals("inbox"))
        {
            uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        }
        else if(folder.equals("sent"))
        {
                uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        }
        try{
            Log.d("folder","inside of inbox");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Log.d("checking","1111111111111");
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Log.d("checking","2222222222");
            Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
            Log.d("checking","333333333333");
            Element rootElement = document.createElement("SMSBackUp");
            Log.d("checking","444444444");
            rootElement.setAttribute("category", folder);
            Log.d("checking","5555555555");
            rootElement.setAttribute("owener", "gaurav");      
            Log.d("checking","6666666666");             
            cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
            Log.d("checking",""+cur);
            Log.d("checking","7777777777777");
            while (cur.moveToNext()) 
            {
                Log.d("checking","88888888");
                Element smsElement = document.createElement("sms");
                rootElement.appendChild(smsElement);

                Element text = document.createElement("text");
                smsElement.appendChild(text);
                text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cur.getString(11)));

                Element phonenoElement = document.createElement("number");
                smsElement.appendChild(phonenoElement);
                phonenoElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cur.getString(2)));

                Element nameElement = document.createElement("author");
                smsElement.appendChild(nameElement);
                nameElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(getContact(cur.getString(2))));                 
            }
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
            Properties outFormat = new Properties();
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
            outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
            OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
            String xmlString = output.toString();
            Log.d("output xml",xmlString);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("execption ","can not create back up" +e);
        }
    }
    private String getContact(String number)
    {

        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        String returnName= "";
        if(cur.getCount() > 0)
        {
            while(cur.moveToNext())
            {
                  String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                  Log.d("Contact","ID:" + id );
                  String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  Log.d("Contact","name:" + name);
                  if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
                  {
                      Cursor pcur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=?",new String[]{number},null);
                      int numindex = pcur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
                      if(pcur.moveToFirst())
                      {
                          String dbNum = pcur.getString(numindex);
                          if(dbNum.equals(number))
                          {
                              returnName = name;
                              Log.d("number","number:" + dbNum);
                          }
                          else 
                          {
                              Log.d("number","numbers dont match!");
                          }
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          Log.d("number", "no result");
                      }
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                       Log.d("number", "No Number");
                  }
            }
        }
        return returnName;
    }

}
```

}

**logcat view**

```
04-05 12:00:07.770: D/reading sms(456): inside of create backup for inbox
04-05 12:00:07.830: D/animation(456): animation should be Start
04-05 12:00:07.830: D/folder(456): inside of inbox
04-05 12:00:07.858: D/checking(456): 1111111111111
04-05 12:00:07.860: D/checking(456): 2222222222
04-05 12:00:07.881: D/checking(456): 333333333333
04-05 12:00:07.890: D/checking(456): 444444444
04-05 12:00:07.920: D/checking(456): 5555555555
04-05 12:00:07.920: D/checking(456): 6666666666
04-05 12:00:07.920: D/checking(456): null
04-05 12:00:07.920: D/checking(456): 7777777777777
04-05 12:00:07.920: E/execption(456): can not create back upjava.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: your cursor is geting null when you move your cursor to moveToNext() NPE.

Comment: @PadmaKumar hi thanx for quick reply sir at the i am checking after creation in very first line ...

Comment: @PadmaKumar cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
            Log.d("checking",""+cur);
here itslef it is giving me null value how to resolve the issue i am new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//because of the case sensitive your condition is filed

change your **Inbox to inbox**

or try with

```
equalsIgnoreCase()

      {
            this.readSms("inbox");
 Log.d("entering into ","inbox");
        }
    }
    public void readSms(String folder)
    {

        if(folder.equals("inbox"))

uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
}
```